# on provision of seven (7) days written notice

Tags: phrases, expressions

I was reading a legal contract and came across this sentence about the termination of the contract:

> This Agreement may be terminated by either Party on provision of seven
>   (7) days written notice to the other Party.

Two questions:
1) "on provision of": Does this mean "on the action of providing a seven days written notice", which I think technically means the day the notice is provided but not seven days later?

2) "Seven days written notice": Does this legally mean a notice to inform that the contract shall be terminated seven days later? I ask this because "seven days written notice" in itself doesn't express the intention to terminate the contract.

Comment: Either party may (1) provide the other with a piece of paper which has on it (2)  writing or printed text saying  that the contract will expire in seven days.

Comment: That 7 days is sometimes interpreted as 7 **work** days.

Comment: Whatever you do, do not take legal advice from random strangers encountered on the Internet.  Not even what might appear to be a trivial piece of interpretation of a simple English sentence.  Legal English is well strange.

Answer (score 1):

1) "On provision of" means under the circumstance of.  If something happens, then something else will happen.

2) "Seven days written notice"- This means if the contract is to be terminated, it must be done with a written notice- speaking out loud someone's intent is not enough.  This notice must be filed 7 days before the contract is terminated.  The contract remains in effect for those 7 days, but you can make plans to exit it.

This latter only provides parameters for exiting the contract, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/notice) gives the particular usage of **notice**

> 2.1 A formal declaration of one's intention to end an agreement, typically one concerning employment or tenancy, at a specified time.

with the example

> his employers gave him two weeks' notice

Similarly you might get, say, one minute's notice that a train will depart, or that an interval in a concert is due to end.